# invoke interceptor before opening any jsp page

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to invoke a interceptor before opening any jsp  page in spring mvc application.

My all jsp pages are in webapps folder.

can anyone provide me detail how it can be do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant "i want to invoke an interceptor on any request", right?
Assuming this, in you dispatcher-context you can configure your interceptors, for example:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/login"/>
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/css/**"/>
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/js/**"/>
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/fonts/*.*"/>
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/img/**"/>
        <bean id="checkListInterceptor" class="your.package.Interceptor">
            <property name="userService" ref="webappUserService" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

your interceptor implementation should be somethink like:

```
public class CheckListInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {


    private IWebappUserService userService;

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object arg2, Exception excp)
            throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object arg2, ModelAndView mav) throws Exception {
        //do stuf..
        request.setAttribute("attrName", attrValue);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            Object arg2) throws Exception {
        return true; //watch it: returning false prevents page to be served!
    }


    public void setUserService(IWebappUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

}
```